# How to update from 0.4.1 Loki to 5.1 Hera

Tags: release-loki, updates, release-hera

I ran into issue while trying to update my OS 0.4.1 to the latest version through the *AppCenter* and got the following error message:

> W: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com loki Release' does not have a Release file.
> W: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
> W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
> W: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
> W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details

What should I do? I don't want to have to buy a new license in order to download the 5.1 version. :)

Answer (score 2):

> trying to update my OS 0.4.1 to the latest version

The ability to easily upgrade to the new version has only been introduced in elementary OS 5.0. I believe this was also the reason behind the version numbering shift.

> I don't whant to buy new license to download the 5.1 version. :)

You do not need to buy a new licence. elementary OS is free and open source, users are just encouraged to donate to the elementary OS team when they they download the iso (after all, developers need to eat). The 'pay what you want' model allows for typing a custom value, including 0.

[image]

So, download a new 5.1 .iso, backup your files, and install the new version. Unfortunately, there is no **practical** way of updating from the AppCenter from the 0.4 to 5.1. From 5.0 upward though, re-installs are no longer necessary.

Comment: Does that mean we're going to be able to upgrade from elementary 5 to elementary 6?