# Try Before Buy?

Tags: bluetooth

I have been trying numerous Linux Distros over the past few weeks. Unfortunately they all have had trouble with Bluetooth connectivity between my Dell laptop and mouse and audio devices. The devices connect but some time later they disconnect. Reconntion becomes a huge ordeal with reboots and manual reconnects. I would like to try Elementary OS but I don't want to buy it if it has the same Bluetooth issues. Is there a way to get it on a trial basis?

Comment: Look at the answer here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/22036/how-to-update-from-0-4-1-loki-to-5-1-hera/22037#22037. It shows how to download the iso file for free, by typing 0 in the custom box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be impolitic but I'm going to give you a straight answer because honesty is what we should be striving for IMO.

Bluetooth support in Linux is twitchy no matter which distribution you run.

I've found that on Ubuntu and elementary installing "Bluetooth Manager" can be helpful, but honestly I find every distro I've tried to be fairly inconsistent when connecting and disconnecting multiple BT devices.

It DOES work though. I regularly use a pair of BT Bose headphones as well as a nice Harman Kardon speaker set to Elementary via BT and it works great. You just have to be willing to fiddle with it a bit, sometimes things like removing/forgetting the device and re-pairing before re-connecting.

Also in the realm of honesty, it's not all sunshine and roses in Bluetooth land on Windows either, and I've seen the same kind of twitchiness there.

Apple seems to have the most solid BT support, probably because their BT stack is more mature as they shipped BT devices before anybody else.

Good luck and I hope you find an operating system you enjoy working with.

Comment: Thank you @feoh. I appreciate your candor. I will continue to search for a great distro and will try elementary too.